# How do i make a variable value changeable in different blocks of code in php,laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, persistence

The task is to fetch json user data from an api and store it in array. Then be able to make changes to it different routes.

Here is a sample of the data from the api, they are 10 in total and in an array.

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
```

i fetched the data using this:

```
$jsonurl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"; 
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);


global $userData;
$userData = json_decode($json);
```

I displayed the data in a /users route with this

```
Route::get('/users', function(){

        global $userData;
        echo json_encode($userData);
});
```

I was told to get set a /delete route that deletes the last object from the array.

```
Route::get('/delete', function(){
    global $userData;
    $lastObjIndex = count($userData) -1;

    array_splice($userData, $lastObjIndex,1);
    //print_r('last user deleted');
    echo json_encode($userData);
    $userData = $userData;

});
```

The problem is that the delete route does not only works once(it does not delete subsequent last objects and returns the same thing when the route is accessed again) and does not show any change in when i access the users route. The data isn't stored in the server.

I feel there is something i don't know about that could help with this. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: if you want to remove the last item in an array you could use something like this



global $userData;
$lastElement = last($userData);
unset($lastElement);